# Laravel make internal links with parsedown library

Tags: php, laravel, parsedown

after installing erusev/parsedown library package i want to make internal links with `Markdowns` like with this code:

```
$Parsedown = new Parsedown();
echo $Parsedown->text("* [Hello](#hello)  
                            * [Hello World](#hello-world)
                            * [Another section](#new-section)

                            ## Hello
                            ### Hello World
                            ## New section");
```

in this code i expect `## New section` must be have `id`, but after show this markdown this part of text doesn't have any `id` to make simple internal link

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the extension of the Parsedown class. You just need to include the ParsedownExtra.php file (or if you are using Composer, just composer require erusev/parsedown-extra) and make an instance of the ParsedownExtra class. See [more](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/issues/306)

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you show me how can i create internal link on this link : http://parsedown.org/extra/ ? thanks

Comment: I hope this will help you do initial code https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/